# Why does the sort not work?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c++11

the error is: 
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2159:29: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
    if (__comp(*__i, *__first))

I am passing 2 strings X and Y. Now the sort should compare XY and YX and then return the X if XY>YX or return Y. X and Y will have values like - 33 or 9999.

```
string Solution::largestNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
int  i,n;
vector<string> B;
string str;
for(i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
{
    B[i]=to_string(A[i]);
}
sort(A.begin(), A.end(),[](const string lhs, const string rhs){
  return rhs+lhs < lhs+rhs;
  });
  for(i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
  {
      str+= to_string(A[i]);
  }
  return str;}
```

Comment: Offtopic: can you prove that such comparison is indeed strict total order, that is that there are no such three strings A, B and C that A<B, B<C and C<A?

Comment: Why would it work? You are trying to sort container `A`, which contains *integers*, but supplying a comparison function, which compares *strings* (!). How did you expect it to work?

Comment: either sort B, or change your comparison function to compare ints.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `std::sort` on a range from `A` which is  a `std::vector<int>`, so the compare function should compare `int`-s.

You could fill `B` initially with 0,1, .... `A.size()-1` then, given two indexes `i1` and `i2` to compare, construct the strings and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

> the error is: `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2159:29: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] if (__comp(*__i, *__first))`
>
> ```
> sort(A.begin(), A.end(),[](const string lhs, const string rhs){...});
> ```

Your `sort` comparator is expecting to compare two `std::string`s.  The element type of `A` is `int`.  You created `B` to be a conversion of `A`'s elements to `B`'s element type of `std::string`.  Use `B`.

Other notes:

```
string Solution::largestNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
    int  i,n;                    // n???
    // vector<string> B;         // B is empty.  Calling B[i] will cause a
                                 // segfault for attempting to access memory
                                 // out of bounds.
    vector<string> B(A.size());  // Fix: pass in the size.  Now creates B 
                                 // with size elements that can be accessed. 
    string str;
    // Consider using algorithms like std::transform
    for(i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
    {
        B[i]=to_string(A[i]);    // You won't segfault here now.
    }
    // Corrected your sort.
    sort(B.begin(), B.end(),[](const string lhs, const string rhs){
        return rhs+lhs < lhs+rhs;
    });  
    // Appending should be done on the sorted string vector. Consider using
    // a ranged-based for loop here.
    for(i=0; i<B.size(); i++)
    {
        str+= B[i];
    }
    return str;
}
```